# What is the best way to prep data for serial transmission?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am working on a C# program which will communicate with a VFD using the Mitsubishi communication protocol.

I am preparing several methods to create an array of bytes to be sent out.

Right now, I have typed up more of a brute-force method of preparing and sending the bytes.

```
        public void A(Int16 Instruction, byte WAIT, Int32 Data )
    {
        byte[] A_Bytes = new byte[13];
        A_Bytes[0] = C_ENQ;
        A_Bytes[1] = 0x00;
        A_Bytes[2] = 0x00;
        A_Bytes[3] = BitConverter.GetBytes(Instruction)[0];
        A_Bytes[4] = BitConverter.GetBytes(Instruction)[1];
        A_Bytes[5] = WAIT;
        A_Bytes[6] = BitConverter.GetBytes(Data)[0];
        A_Bytes[7] = BitConverter.GetBytes(Data)[1];
        A_Bytes[8] = BitConverter.GetBytes(Data)[2];
        A_Bytes[9] = BitConverter.GetBytes(Data)[3];
        Int16 SUM = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            SUM += A_Bytes[i];
        }
        A_Bytes[10] = BitConverter.GetBytes(SUM)[0];
        A_Bytes[11] = BitConverter.GetBytes(SUM)[1];
        A_Bytes[12] = C_CR;
        itsPort.Write(A_Bytes, 0, 13);
    }
```

However, something seems very inefficient about this. Especially the fact that I call GetBytes() so often.

Is this a good method, or is there a vastly shorter/faster one?

MAJOR UPDATE:

turns out, the mitsubishi structure is a little wonky in how it does all this.

Instead of working with bytes, it works with ascii chars. so while ENQ is still 0x05, an instruction code of E1, for instance, is actually 0x45 and 0x31.

This might actually make things easier.

Comment: Are these fixed length packets?

Comment: Yes. And they come in various formats. This is one of about ten, each of different size and structure.

Comment: Are there any restrictions against (1) you using "unsafe" code (i,e, raw pointers) or (2) targeting CPU architectures that have mandatory alignment requirements (i.e require an int to be aligned on a word boundary), or (3) architectures that are big endian.

Comment: no particular restrictions, there. But if it involves a lot of pointers and endian changes, I think my current code will suffice.

Comment: You could create `structs`, with an explicit and/or sequential [layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind(v=vs.110).aspx), and assign e.g. integer values directly, For "byte loops" to a specific offset, you can cast them (using unsafe code) to a byte* pointer, and access those bytes directly.

Answer (score 0):

Even without changing your algorithm, this can be made a bit more efficient and a bit more c#-like. If concating two array bothers you, that is of course optional.

```
    var instructionBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(instruction); 
    var dataBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(data);

    var contentBytes = new byte[] { 
        C_ENQ, 0x00, 0x00, instructionBytes[0], instructionBytes[1], wait,
        dataBytes[0], dataBytes[1], dataBytes[2], dataBytes[3]          
    };

    short sum = 0;
    foreach(var byteValue in contentBytes)
    {
        sum += byteValue;
    }

    var sumBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(sum);

    var messageBytes = contentBytes.Concat(new byte[] { sumBytes[0], sumBytes[1], C_CR } );

    itsPort.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
```

What I would suggest though, if you find yourself writing a lot of code like this, is to consider wrapping this up into a `Message` class. This code would form the basis of your constructor. You could then vary behavior (make things longer, shorter etc) with inheritance (or composition) and deal with the message as an object rather than a byte array.

Incidentally, you may see margin gains from using `BinaryWriter` rather than `BitConverter` (maybe?), but it's more hassle to use. `(byte)(sum >> 8)` is another option as well, which I think is the fastest actually and probably makes the most sense in your use case.

Comment: I wasn't sure. Does casting to a (byte) grab only the relevant bits, or does it try to translate the whole value into a byte?

Comment: it takes the last byte.

Comment: *"Last byte"* is ambiguous, since neither scan direction or the byte order (big endian, little endian or natural order) have been specified.  The proper answer is the "least significant byte".

Comment: @sawdust No, life is ambiguous. The CLI makes no promises about the endianness of things. The cast grabs the byte at the top of the evaluation stack.  BitConverter has a IsLittleEndian property, allowing your to choose, but casting does not. With that in mind "least significant byte" is true most of the time.